# Python: Generic/Templated getters

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, metaprogramming

I have a code that simply fetches a user/s from a database

```
class users:
    def __init__(self):
        self.engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://root:password@127.0.0.1/my_database")
        self.connection = self.engine.connect()
        self.meta = MetaData(bind=self.connection)
        self.users = Table('users', self.meta, autoload = true)

    def get_user_by_user_id(self, user_id):
        stmt = self.users.select().where(self.users.c.user_id == user_id)
        return self.connection.execute(stmt)

    def get_user_by_username(self, username):
        stmt = self.users.select().where(self.users.c.username == username)
        return self.connection.execute(stmt)

    def get_users_by_role_and_company(self, role, company)
        stmt = self.users.select().where(self.users.c.role == role).where(self.users.c.company == company)
        return self.connection.execute(stmt)
```

Now, what I want to do is to make the getters generic like so:

```
class users:
    def __init__(self):
        self.engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://root:password@127.0.0.1/my_database")
        self.connection = self.engine.connect()
        self.meta = MetaData(bind=self.connection)
        self.users = Table('users', self.meta, autoload = true)

    def get_user(self, **kwargs):
        '''How do I make this generic function?'''
```

So, instead of calling something like this:

```
u = users()
u.get_user_by_user_id(1)
u.get_user_by_username('foo')
u.get_users_by_role_and_company('Admin', 'bar')
```

I would just call the generic function like so:

```
u = users()
u.get_user(user_id=1)
u.get_user(username='foo')
u.get_user(role='Admin', company='bar')
```

---

So far, this was what I could think of:

```
def get_user(**kwargs):
    where_clause = ''
    for key, value in kwargs.items():
        where_clause += '{} == {} AND '.format(key, value)
    where_clause = where_clause[:-5] # remove final AND
    stmt = "SELECT * FROM {tablename} WHERE {where_clause};".format(tablename='users', where_clause=where_clause)
    return self.connection.execute(stmt)
```

Is there any way that I could use the ORM style to create the statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fully generalized, so any combination of legal field names is accepted as long as a field of that name exists in the table. The magic is in `getattr`, which allows us to look up the field we're interested in dynamically (and raises `AttributeError` if called with a non-existent field name):

```
def get_user(self, **kwargs):
    # Basic query
    stmt = self.users.select()

    # Query objects can be refined piecemeal, so we just loop and
    # add new clauses, assigning back to stmt to build up the query
    for field, value in kwargs.items():
        stmt = stmt.where(getattr(self.users.c, field) == value)

    return self.connection.execute(stmt)
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what i've been looking for.

Answer (score 0):

But you did all the hard work.. It's just a matter of combining the functions you created, initializing the input variables and throwing some `if` statements in the mix.

```
def get_user(self, user_id=0, username='', role='', company=''):
    if user_id:
        stmt = self.users.select().where(self.users.c.user_id == user_id)
        return self.connection.execute(stmt)
    elif username:
        stmt = self.users.select().where(self.users.c.username == username)
        return self.connection.execute(stmt)
    elif role and company:
        stmt = self.users.select().where(self.users.c.role == role).where(self.users.c.company == company)
        return self.connection.execute(stmt)
    else:
        print('Not adequate information given. Please enter "ID" or "USERNAME", or "ROLE"&"COMPANY"')
        return
```

Note that `user_id` has been initialized to `0` so that it has a boolean of `False`. If a 0 id is possible, set it directly to `False` instead. So, since the input cannot be 'random', is there a reason you want to do it with `**kwargs`?

---

Alternatively, if the numberof combinations are too many to code, i would go a different route (SQL-injection-valnurable script incoming!) and that is the following:

```
def get_user(self, query):
    form_query = 'SELECT user FROM {} WHERE {}'.format(table_name, query)
    # now execute it and return whatever it is you want returned
```

You are no longer passing variables to the function but rather a string which will appended to the query and executed.
**Needless to say you have to be very careful with that.**

Comment: But this makes me code all the possible combinations. In the users table, there are at least 13 fields that can be used to query a user.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
def get_user(self, **kwargs):
    if 'user_id' in kwargs:
        (...)
    elif  'username' in kwargs:
        (...)
    elif all(a in ['role','company'] for a in kwargs):
        (...)
    else:
        (...)
```

Comment: Pet peeve: Don't use `map` if you need a `lambda` to do it; it's more verbose, slower and uglier than an equivalent generator expression if you need to resort to `lambda`s (particularly if the generator expression could avoid the function call entirely). You could use `map` with a built-in in this case anyway: `all(map(('role', 'company').__contains__, kwargs))`, but the gains are likely tiny; you could just do `all(k in ('role', 'company') for k in kwargs)` and it's generally considered more Pythonic.

Comment: Similarly, `'user_id' in kwargs` is a more efficient and correct way to test for the presence of a key than `kwargs.get('user_id')`; the latter will incorrectly indicate a missing key even if the key is present and has a "falsy" value.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up.